# CakePHP 3 Filestorage Plugin Triggering the ImageProcessingListener to delete versions

Tags: php, cakephp

https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/blob/3.0/docs/Home.md

I have two tables

ProductStylesTable.php and ProductStyleImagesTable.php which extends ImageStorageTable which is connect to my FileStorage Table in my sql that was created with the migration tool.

Upload works fine.

```
// ProductStylesController.php 

 public function upload($product_style_id = null) {
      $this->ProductStyles->ProductStyleImages->upload( $product_style_id, $entity)




//ProductStyleImagesTable.php

class ProductStyleImagesTable extends ImageStorageTable { 

//initialize code...

 public function upload($product_style_id, $entity) {

    $entity = $this->patchEntity($entity, [
        'adapter' => 'Local',
        'model' => 'ProductStyles',
        'foreign_key' => $product_style_id,
    ]);
    return $this->save($entity);

}
```

Awesome, ProductStyleImages is listening for the upload method and places it in the appropriate folder. I was hoping this would work the same for delete.

So I called

```
  //ProductStylesController.php
  $this->ProductStyles->ProductStyleImages->delete($fileStorage_id)

  //In my ProductStyleImagesTable.php
  public function delete($fileStorageID = null) {

    //deleting the row, hoping for ImageProcessingListener to pick it up?
    $FileStorageTable = TableRegistry::get('FileStorage');
    $query = $FileStorageTable->query();
    $query->delete()
        ->where(['id' => $fileStorageID ])
        ->execute();


}
```

I get an error that delete must be compatible with the interface. So to avoid this conflict I renamed my function to 'removeImage'. It works in removing the row but the Listener isn't picking it up. I looked in ImageStorageTable.php and FileStorageTable.php. I see the afterDelete methods. But i'm unsure how to trigger them since i'm unsure how to configure my delete methods to match the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted wrong, it is this way

```
$entity = $this->get($fileStorageID);
$result = $this->delete($entity);
```